# Subversion Unexpected server error 500 on checkout

Tags: svn

I'm trying to build Blockly-games on my PC.
Following the guide on the [github page](https://github.com/google/blockly-games/wiki/Build)

After 'svn checkout https://github.com/google/blockly-games' in my terminal I get the following error: 
*svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/google/blockly-games'
svn: E175002: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/google/blockly-games'*

I've never used subversion before so maybe I got wrong configuration settings.

On the internet I also found that the folder in which I want to checkout doesn't have the right permission, but also chmod 777 does give the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was some temporary problem on GitHub. Checkout should work now.