# Error 500 checking out from github with svn

Tags: github, svn

I try to checkout my repository *user/bar* on GitHub using the cli-version of `svn`. This fails with error 500.

Note: Similar questions have been asked before, but are either slightly different or have (for my case) unsatisfying answers:

- [Error Connecting to GitHub from SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043764/error-connecting-to-github-from-svn) got a different error message
- [git svn gives 500 internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717508/git-svn-gives-500-internal-server-error) got the same error, but only with `git svn clone` not with native `svn`
- [Subversion Unexpected server error 500 on checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548019/subversion-unexpected-server-error-500-on-checkout) had exactly the same problem, but it seemed to have been a temporary problem on GitHub
- [Community Forum](https://github.community/t/getting-500-internal-server-error-when-performing-svn-checkout/253480) describes exactly the same problem, but got no response

[GitHub Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/working-with-subversion-on-github/support-for-subversion-clients) says: *make an empty checkout of the repository*,

```
$ svn co --depth empty https://github.com/user/repo
> Checked out revision 1.
$ cd repo
```

So I tried to check out my repositories of *foo* (created months ago) and *bar* (created recently), and - as a cross check - a non-existing repository *baz*:

```
$ svn co --depth empty https://github.com/user/foo
Checked out revision 4949.
$ svn co --depth empty https://github.com/user/bar
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/user/bar'
svn: E175002: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/user/bar'
$ svn co --depth empty https://github.com/user/baz
Authentication realm: <https://github.com:443> GitHub
Password for 'user': ****************************************

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/user/baz'
svn: E160013: '/user/baz' path not found
```

Findings:

- basically it works, otherwise *foo* would not be fine
- *bar* exists, otherwise the error would would be like *baz*

A temporary problem seems unlikely (becaus *foo* works), but to be sure I've waited for a couple of days - no change. Configuration of *foo* and *bar* is identical (to the best of my knowledge).

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

More than a week after the original attempt it suddenly works as expected. So if you happen to run into the same problem:

- it *might* affect only selected repositories
- the temporary failure *might* last for quite some time

Comment: @RohitGupta this looks like a valid answer.

Comment: @slowfox I believe this is a sporadic or temporary problem on GitHub's side and you cannot do anything to solve it. Contact GitHub with a bug report.

Comment: @bahrep - You are right, it looks like it.  I can't find what my action was.  And even if I could, I don't think that I can change it.